# SQL query Performance when using Datetime in where / On clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the 5l record in table. need to query...Which is one is query fast,Input parameter @RegistrationFrom DATE,@RegistrationTo  DATE

Approach #1:

```
WHERE 
    CAST(Act.RegistrationOn AS DATE) BETWEEN CAST(@RegistrationFrom AS DATE) 
                                         AND CAST(@RegistrationTo AS DATE)
```

Approach #2 - convert into datetime:

```
DECLARE @From DATETIME, @Todate DATETIME;

SELECT @From = @RegistrationFrom;
SELECT @Todate = DATEADD(day, 1, @RegistrationTo);

WHERE 
    Act.RegistrationOn BETWEEN @From AND @Todate
```

Approach #3:

WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR, Act.RegistrationOn,101)  BETWEEN @From AND @Todate

I ma getting fast response approach 3 than above 1,2.
How it is working?

Comment: Why you don't you test it? That is the only way to know for sure on your configuration

Comment: Why are you `casting as date` everything in approach 1?

Comment: we are passing from & To date from UI as filter

Comment: Be very carefull here! Your `BETWEEN CAST(@RegistrationFrom AS DATE) AND CAST(@RegistrationTo AS DATE)` would NOT include entries from the last day, if they have a time portion!

Comment: Is this question solved? Do you need further help? Please allow me one hint: It would be very kind of you to tick the acceptance check below the best answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Once you crossed the 15 points border yourself you are - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

I would write the query as:

```
SELECT @Todate = DATEADD(day, 1, @RegistrationTo);
. . .
WHERE Act.RegistrationOn >= @From AND 
      Act.RegistrationOn < @Todate
```

Whether you use variables or a cast on the variable should have no or little affect on performance.  More important considerations are the use of indexes and interpretability (does the code do what you intend).

Aaron Bertrand has a very good [blog](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) on why you shouldn't use `BETWEEN` for dates.

As for the first version . . . it is actually more reasonable than you might think.  In general, function calls prevent the use of indexes on columns.  However, SQL Server makes an exception for conversion of a `datetime` to `date`.  So, it will still use an index.

That said, I would still go with the above version.

Comment: It seems that the parameters are both handed in as `DATETIME`. If they have a time portion, this would lead to unexpected and wrong results...

Answer (score 0):

Both options are equivalent from performance point of view:

**Approach 1**

```
WHERE Act.RegistrationOn AS DATE BETWEEN CAST(@RegistrationFrom AS DATE) AND CAST(@RegistrationTo AS DATE)
```

**Approach 2**

```
WHERE RegistrationOn BETWEEN @From AND @Todate
```

Each casting in Approach 1 is executed only once and not for each row as you might expected.

For clarity, I would take option 2 or even better send the parameter with the right type to this query.

Also, an index on RegistrationOn column would definitively help. Please note a CAST on RegistrationOn column has been removed from Approach 1 as this would prevent SQL Server to use this index.

Comment: what abt this CAST(Act.RegistrationOn AS DATE) will apply for each row?

Comment: The casting on `Act.RegistrationOn` would prevent sql server to use any indexes that might include this column. However, if the column is of type `datetime`, the casting to date is redundant anyway. since datetime can be compared to date.

Comment: Mihai, don't know, maybe OP wants it this way, but with `BETWEEN` and a `CAST AS DATE` for the high border you would not include data from the last day, if there is a time...

Comment: @ZoharPeled, the cast of datetime to date is sargable actually: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea...

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
WITH MyPrms AS
(
    SELECT CAST(@RegistrationFrom AS DATE) AS fromD
          ,CAST(@RegistrationTo AS DATE) + 1 AS toD
)
SELECT *
FROM MyPrms
CROSS JOIN Act
WHERE Act.Registration>=fromD AND Act.RegistrationOn<toD;
```

It is fully inlineable (in VIEWS, functions...) and sargable (optimizer can use indexes)

### EDIT just for clearity

By adding `+1` to your upper border date (which was casted to a timeless `DATE` before, the upper border is midnight **after** the last day. By using a `<` you will get all data from the full day. `BETWEEN` includes the border which can lead to unexpected errors...

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR, Act.RegistrationOn,101)  BETWEEN @From AND @Todate
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.